# How can I also echo the next line with regex?

Tags: php, regex

I am using the code below to find specific text and then echo the whole line. However, I want it to **also** echo the line below it too.

Is that doable?

Thanks

```
$file = 'file.txt';
$searchfor = "$groupName";

$contents = file_get_contents($file);

$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');

$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";


if (preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
    echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}else{
    echo "No matches found for - $searchfor";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match an optional next line with

```php
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*(?:\R.*)?/m";
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$pattern` - the defined `$pattern`
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(?:\R.*)?` - an optional sequence of any line break sequence and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

Comment: Perfect! That did it thanks. New to regex so your breakdown was extremely helpful. Thanks again.